# Combine a SELECT and INSERT Query into one...possible?

Tags: mysql, insert

Trying to figure out a MySQL statement, and this is kind of a general query question so I am not using any set index...so bear with me. :)

Is there a way to combine these two queries.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ID='123';
if (NUM_ROWS == 0) {
    INSERT INTO tableName (ID) VALUES (123)
}
```

Basically, I want to check if a certain entry exists and if it doesn't I want to create it.  Figured I might be able to hit the DB once instead of twice.

The end goal is to create the row only if one doesn't exist first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `ID` column is the `PRIMARY KEY` or has a `UNIQUE` constraint, then simply try to add it with `IGNORE` so you don't get any error message (only a warning):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tableName (ID) 
  VALUES (123)
```

If it isn't, this will work in general:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (ID)
  SELECT 123
  FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT * 
          FROM tableName 
          WHERE ID = 123
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) statement

Comment: What if you only want to insert if the row doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

As @uzi pointed out, you can use the `REPLACE` statement. However, that will **delete** the record before insertion, and that might now be what you want.

There is also the MySQL extension [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), but then again you will have to add something to the update clause in case the record is found.

**Edit:**
Oh and also those two statements work for duplicated unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a simple `INSERT IGNORE INTO` in those cases. Keep in mind that this might have other side-effects, like other conversion errors getting converted into mere warnings.